# Cannot convert .py file into .exe in Pycharm

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, pyinstaller, exe

I'm trying to create .exe file in pycharm. When I'm installing pyinstaller by 'import pyinstaller' it gets error.

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 180, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 204, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 318, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 127, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 473, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 341, in resolve
    name, crit = self._merge_into_criterion(r, parent=None)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 172, in _merge_into_criterion
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 139, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 143, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 129, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 30, in _iter_built
    for version, func in infos:
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 269, in iter_index_candidate_infos
    result = self._finder.find_best_candidate(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 879, in find_best_candidate
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 824, in find_all_candidates
    page_candidates = list(page_candidates_it)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\sources.py", line 134, in page_candidates
    yield from self._candidates_from_page(self._link)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 783, in process_project_url
    html_page = self._link_collector.fetch_page(project_url)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 512, in fetch_page
    return _get_html_page(location, session=self.session)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 422, in _get_html_page
    resp = _get_html_response(url, session=session)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 120, in _get_html_response
    resp = session.get(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\session.py", line 449, in request
    return super().request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py", line 53, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connection.py", line 359, in connect
    conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connection.py", line 500, in _connect_tls_proxy
    return ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 432, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 474, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 997, in _create
    raise ValueError("check_hostname requires server_hostname")
ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname
```

Comment: You should add some sample code to your question

Answer (score 1):

This is not how pyinstaller works. Rather than *importing* pyinstaller into your program, you need to *run* pyinstaller pointing at your program.

From the [docs](https://www.pyinstaller.org/):

Install PyInstaller from PyPI:

`pip install pyinstaller`

Go to your program’s directory and run:

`pyinstaller yourprogram.py`

Comment: Yeah I tried to write this too> pip install pyinstaller in terminal, but it's also not working, gets error.

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: Same error like above

Comment: This error:   'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: What happens when you just type `pip` into your cmd?

Comment: I created exe file but it's not opening when I click it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use auto-py-to-exe

`pip install auto-py-to-exe`
to run it
`$ auto-py-to-exe`

Comment: I created exe file but it's not opening when I click it. When I click it , it's loading 1 second and not opening